# Mongodump getting blank folders

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run this command from a `remote ssh`

```
mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 27017 --username user --password pass --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24
```

However, all I am getting is blank folders for each collections.

What am I doing wrong?

Info (if it matters):
Source Mongodb is on Windows Server
And SSH is of a remote Ubuntu Machine

Here is the terminal output:

```
connected to: ip.ip.ip.ip:27017
Thu Feb 18 00:46:01.757 all dbs
Thu Feb 18 00:46:01.809 DATABASE: admin  to     /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24/admin
Thu Feb 18 00:46:01.903 DATABASE: anthony_data       to     /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24/anthony_data
Thu Feb 18 00:46:02.004 DATABASE: temp_data  to     /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24/temp_data
Thu Feb 18 00:46:02.104 DATABASE: zoomy   to     /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-24/zoomy
```

So it creates empty folder for all collections. But there is no bson in it

Comment: Surely there is some output in the terminal that should give you some indication of what is wrong. Include the output if you are still unsure.

Comment: Can you add --db <dbname>

Comment: @RamachandraReddy It would not mattter, since `mongodump` would just dump all databases ( that the user has access to  ) by default. Of course if the user lacked permission to list databases, then that would be another issue. But as stated, there is still going to be output that shows some explanation, even if the OP does not understand how to inperpret that output.

Comment: @Blakes Seven updated the question with `terminal output` can you please help, thanks

Answer (score 28):

Check that your copy of mongodump and the database itself is the same version.

I had the exact same problem (complete with no terminal output or logs) when I tried to do a dump of a mongo 3.2.4 server with a 2.4.1 mongodump client. Removing the older client and installing the newer one resolved it immediately.

Comment: my version matches still the same issue

Comment: This was the problem for me. I was running the DB using downloaded binaries, but dumping with an aptitude package. Anyone using binaries just make sure you're invoking mongodump from the same set of executables.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the default mongodb-client deb package with Ubuntu. I removed those and installed the mongodb-org-tools package from mongodb.com https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=2.36209632.1945690590.1499275806-1594815486.1499275806

They have other install instructions for your specific OS if you are not on Ubuntu https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community