# Getting empty folder when using mongodump to back up my MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Basically, I have a problem with using `mongodump` to back up my MongoDB.

This is the general syntax I use in SSH:

```
mongodump -d myDatabaseName -o ~/backups/my_backup
```

This is the resulting message:

```
Fri Apr 22 20:39:57.304 DATABASE: myDatabaseName   to     /root/backups/my_backup/myDatabaseName
```

This simply generates a blank folder with no files in it whatsoever. The actual database is fairly large, so not sure what's going on.

I would also like to add that my mongodump client and my MongoDB version are both the same (version 2.4.9).

Not sure how to go about fixing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Off topic for StackOverflow. [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar question as [Mongodump getting blank folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470766/mongodump-getting-blank-folders/44933628#44933628)

There is no accepted answer as of writing my answer. Here is what I did to resolve my issue and I believe it will help you as well.

The default mongodb-client deb package with Ubuntu is the issue. I removed those and installed the mongodb-org-tools package from mongodb.com https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=2.36209632.1945690590.1499275806-1594815486.1499275806

They have other install instructions for your specific OS if you are not on Ubuntu https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the port of mongodb_port as in:
mongodump --port your_number -c the_collection -d the_database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the exact name of the database. If you spell it wrong, this could happen. To confirm, connect to your mongo database and type `show dbs` to see a list of database names. Then make sure that your databasename parameter `-d <databasename>` matches one of those in the list.